# Query optimization for non-equal data connection

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Employee:

```
Empid  STW  --StartWorkTime
------------------------------
1      02:00:00.000
2      03:00:00.000
3      05:30:00.000
```

Table Order:

```
Orderid  PlaceTime
-------------------------------
1        02:22:22.333
2        02:33:33:555
3        03:44:44:111
4        05:45:45:545
```

Request is: connect the orders to which employee placed it by their time relationship., like:

```
Empid   Orderid
--------------------
1       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
```

Assume the last employee off work time = current one on work time.

Currently my solution is:

```
SELECT e.empid, o.orderid
FROM order o
CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP(1) e.empid FROM order e
      WHERE e.STW < o.placetime
      ORDER BY STW DESC) e
```

The solution works fine when table `employee` is small (`order` 1 mil rows, `employee` 50rows, its about 30 sec), but performance drops quickly as `employee` expands (when it's 10000s row, it takes over an hour). is there any solutions to optimize such a case?

Comment: I would recommend you simply add a FK on order which employee has placed it (or make a connection table) and then simply maintain that information - will be much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend indexes.  First, I would fix the query so the subquery uses the employee table (I assume this is a typo in the question):

```
SELECT e.empid, o.orderid
FROM order o CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP(1) e.empid
      FROM employee e
      WHERE e.STW < o.placetime
      ORDER BY STW DESC
     ) e;
```

You want an index on `employee(STW, empid)`.  See if that helps the query.